New contributor despite having more than 200 "points"?
I have been reading this question when I noticed the author is labeled as a new contributor despite the user's reputation and former questions contradict that:

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

I'm not really sure the banner is a bug. I can't really find any documentation on the banner... but as far as I know the banner sticks around for like a week after a contributor 'starts doing stuff'. A user asking 4 questions over 4 days is still 'new'. You can rep cap each day and get 1.4k rep at the end, but 7 days would still be 'new'. (Again I'm assuming the banner sticks around for a week.) If you really want the 'bug' looked at you should probably ask on Meta Meta.

It is not a bug.
On Meta Stack Exchange, refer to this question: What are the exact criteria for the "new contributor" indicator to be shown?

We put the indicator on all the posts you make within your first week
of posting on that specific site. The indicator stays on each post for
a week.

Read the answer for more details.
The user is new to Code Review, started with 1 reputation, plus the association bonus of 100, plus several upvotes on posts this week.

My reading of that quote is that we might see the indicator up to the end of the second week of membership, if the question is posted close to the end of the first week.

@TobySpeight I'm pretty sure I've seen the banner on accounts which have been created months previously. "your first week of posting" only starts the cool down after the user's first post, not account creation. Take for example Silah who's been around for 38 days, but still has the banner.
